# Google Sheets: Split cell without deleting the delimiter

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to split cells that contain an address and the neighbourhood in which this address is located, for example: "Hauptstr. 12, 50937 Köln, Ehrenfeld". The name after "Köln, " is the name of the neighbourhood.

If I use the split command with "Köln, " as a delimiter, the address is split up but without the city (cell 1: Hauptstr. 12, 50937; cell 2: Ehrenfeld).

Is there a possibility to break a cell into two parts but without deleting the delimiter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can try with `REGEXREPLACE()` and then split

Examples here:
https://infoinspired.com/google-docs/spreadsheet/google-sheets-regexreplace-function/

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
=regexextract(A1,regexreplace(A1,"(.+), (.+)","($1), ($2)"))
```